# if ignores the condition JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to set up a div that can only be clicked once, but my if keeps ignoring the condition and I really dont know why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var defaultState = true;
  if (defaultState) {
    defaultState = false;
    $("#element").click(function() {
    //Do stuff to elements
  }
});
```

I tried solving it a different way. I want this condition only to fill one div with context from another one, but only one single time. So I tried making the condition like this: `if($("#element").html().length === 0)` I even checked with the console for the value of my condition, and even if it was at 5000, clearly not 0 anymore, it kept ignoring my condition and went into the if.

Comment: You should use this one? http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have added a event listener `$("#element").click(function() {` it will be bounded to that element. **But** what you can do it to put your `if` inside the click function and give `false` to your flag variable once inside the `if`. 
**The advantage is** you can give the variable `true` again, and you click will run "again".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var defaultState = true;
    $("#element").click(function () {
        if (defaultState) {
            defaultState = false;
            //Do stuff to elements
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you bind the click handler, it's bound. From that point, until you unbind it, that handler will always be triggered.

It sounds like [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) would be what you're looking for:

```
$('#element').one('click', function() {
   //...
});
```

That will only trigger once.

Answer (score 1):

The event handler is already attached that first time through, right after the document.ready runs.

You can just use the jQuery `.one()` event handler.
[jQuery .one() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$("#element").one('click', function() {
    //Do stuff to elements
});
```

Comment: Silly mistake, totally forgot!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element").one('click', function() {
        //Do stuff to elements
    });
});
```

***OR***

```
$("#element").on('click', function(){
    //Do what you want
});

//Later in your code

$("#element").off('click');
```

If you're set on using a flag variable you can do it like this too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var defaultState = true;

    $("#element").click(function(e) {
        if (defaultState) {
            //Do what you want
        }

        defaultState = false;
    }
});
```